# gds.beta.pipeline.nodeClassification.train: Target property not found

Tags: neo4j, graph-data-science

Using Neo4j v4.4 and GDS 2.0. I'm trying to train a model. When I type:

```
CALL gds.beta.pipeline.nodeClassification.train('individual-graph', {
   pipeline: 'pipe',
   nodeLabels: ['PERSON'],
   modelName: 'xmen-model-fastRP',
   targetProperty: 'is_risky',
   metrics: ['F1_WEIGHTED','ACCURACY'],
   randomSeed: 2
   }) YIELD modelInfo
  RETURN
  modelInfo.bestParameters AS winningModel,
  modelInfo.metrics.F1_WEIGHTED.outerTrain AS trainGraphScore,
  modelInfo.metrics.F1_WEIGHTED.test AS testGraphScore
```

I get the following error message:
Failed to invoke procedure `gds.beta.pipeline.nodeClassification.train`: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target property `is_risky` not found in graph with node properties: [[embedding]]

What am I doing wrong? Can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

It means that the property 'is_risky' is not found in the node PERSON. The only existing property is embedding.

Going thru the example in the neo4j documentation (https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/machine-learning/nodeclassification-pipelines/) will give you an idea of what the error is. Below is an example of a similar issue that you are getting.

```
Target property `my_class` not found in graph 
with node properties: [[sizePerStory, class], [sizePerStory]]
```

As you can see, the algorithm will give you a list of properties available for prediction.

Comment: Thanks ! My nodes have multiple properties, not just the "embedding" property. Why are they not detected?

Comment: I don't see your database so maybe 'PERSON' is actually 'Person'? Neo4j is case-sensitive.